# Refreshing previous content page Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a content page with some details and a button named "Update details" to update the content in this page. Another page is opened through the `Navigation.PushAsync` method where I update the details in this page and click the save button.

How can I update the previous page with the new details when I click the save button on the other page?  Should I refresh the previous page on buttonClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the previous page by using the MessagingCenter:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/

You can subscribe to a message in the first page and when you click save on the second page, you can send a message to the first page and update the content on that page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. What i want to know is , How to refresh the page. As in call the method to get data again?

Comment: You can refresh the page by changing it's Content property. For example, you subscribed to a message from the second page in your first page like this:

`MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string> (this, "Hi", (sender, arg) => {
   // Change the Content property of the page
});`

Inside the subscription, you need the change the Content and write the new content of the page.